# Function for the Second Derivative Test

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I wrote the following function. It is based on Mathematica for Rogawski's Calculus, 2nd Ed, 2007, Based on Mathematica 7. See: http://users.rowan.edu/~hassen/Math_Rogawski_Calc.htm, Chapter 14. I made a bunch of different moves.

```
secondDerivativeTest[f] := Module[{fxx, disc, cp, tableData},
  fxx = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]f\);
  disc = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]f\) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]f\) - (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, y\)]f\))^2;
  cp = Solve[Grad[f, {x, y}] == {0, 0}, {x, y}];
  tableData = {x, y, f, fxx, disc} /. cp;
  TableForm[tableData,
   TableHeadings -> {{}, {"x", "y", "f(x,y)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(xx\)]\)(x,y)", "D"}},
   TableAlignments -> Right]]
```

Here's an image to make the reading clearer, and shows the output when applied to a function.

[image]

Now, it doesn't work on this function.

[image]

The Solve command can't deal with the function. So I thought I'd just try a NSolve.

```
NsecondDerivativeTest[f] := Module[{fxx, disc, cp, tableData},
  fxx = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]f\);
  disc = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]f\) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]f\) - (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, y\)]f\))^2;
  cp = NSolve[Grad[f, {x, y}] == {0, 0}, {x, y}];
  tableData = {x, y, f, fxx, disc} /. cp;
  TableForm[tableData,
   TableHeadings -> {{}, {"x", "y", "f(x,y)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(xx\)]\)(x,y)", "D"}},
   TableAlignments -> Right]]
```

But I had to abort.

[image]

Anyone have a suggestion on how to make this work?

**Updated Version:**

I want to thank everyone for their help. I think I've decided on the following procedure, which is a bit easier to understand. Haven't thoroughly tested it, but working thus far. Here is the first step of analysis:

```
f = (y^2 - x + x y + Log[x^2 + y^4 + 1]) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
fx = D[f, x];
fy = D[f, y];
ContourPlot[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> 20, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, fx], Function[{x, y}, fy]},
 Mesh -> {{0}, {0}},
 MeshStyle -> {{Yellow, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}]
```

Which produces this contour plot.

[image]

Now I use Ctrl+t to open the Drawing Tools palette, select the GetCoordinates icon, then do a mouse click at each point where the mesh functions intersect. Then I use (I'm on a Mac) CMD-c to save the points to the clipboard. In an new input cell I type pts =, then I hit CMD-v to past the contents of the clipboard. Here is the result.

```
pts = {{0.6298, -0.1752}, {0.01879, 1.066}, {-0.6601, 0.494}, {-0.631, -0.7183}}
```

Then I use the FindRoot command.

```
cp = FindRoot[{fx == 0, fy == 0}, {x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}] & /@ pts
```

Here's my new code attempt:

```
NewSecondDerivativeTest[f_, cp] := 
 Module[{fxx, disc, class, tableData},
  fxx = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]f\);
  disc = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]f\) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]f\) - (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, y\)]f\))^2;
  class = Which[
    disc == 0, "Fail",
    disc < 0, "Saddle",
    (fxx > 0 && disc > 0), "Min",
    (fxx < 0 && disc > 0), "Max"
    ];
  tableData = {x, y, f, fxx, disc, class} //. cp;
  TableForm[tableData,
   TableHeadings -> {{}, {"x", "y", "f(x,y)", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(xx\)]\)(x,y)", "D", "Class"}},
   TableAlignments -> Right]]
```

Here is an image to make it more readable and the final output.

[image]

Comment: Instead of `f` use a pattern `f_`, perhaps

Comment: If you calculate `Simplify[Grad[f, {x, y}]]`, you'll see that you have components that have factors of `Exp[-(x^2 + y^2}`. And if you look at that, or even do a `Plot3D` on the gradient, you'll see that the graph becomes very flat, close to the $xy$-axis, as you move away from the origin.

Comment: Have you seen Stan Wagon's implementation?

Comment: @MichaelE2. I tried f_. It worked in both `secondDerivativeTest[f_]:=...` and `NsecondDerivativeTest[f_]:=...` with the expression `f=x^3+y^4-6x-2y^2`, but `NsecondDerivativeTest[f_]=...` did not work with the expression `f = (y^2 - x + x y + Log[x^2 + y^4 + 1]) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]`.

Comment: @murray. Not sure of the point you are making. I added a contour plot to my original post. Looks like there should be four critical values.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Found it. Gonna spend some time right now going over the whole Chapter 12 on Solve.

Comment: Yep, 4 critical points indeed. Guided by your contour plot, they may be located by using `FindRoot`. Obtain all 4 as follows: `FindRoot[Grad[f, {x, y}] == 0, {x, First@#}, {y, Last@#}] & /@ {{0, 
   0}, {-0.5, -1}, {0.25, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}`.

Comment: @murray Use your idea to update my function. I've added as an update to my original post above. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Use part of your idea and murray's idea to update my function.

Comment: @Guess who it is: Stan Wagon's implementation where? Are you perhaps referring to function `LowestCriticalPoint` in Chapter 13 of his *Mathematica in Action*, 3rd edition?

Comment: @murray, I'm far away from my copy of the second edition, but I do recall he had a routine there for performing this test. I don't know if it's still in the third edition.

Comment: @murray On page 324 of the third edition, he write a function ClassifyCP2D.

Comment: @David: The issue in the original question was not the classification of critical points, but rather locating the critical points (for that nasty function).

Comment: @murray Yes, it is in section 12.7, pages 318-322.